# Conditional eager loading and $with array for Laravel Model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have an interesting situation where eager loading is interacting poorly with Telescope on my local dev environment. Therefore, I have the desire to turn off eager loading for my Post model on local. But I can't figure out how to do this conditionally. For instance, I'd like to to do something like this:

```
class Post extends Model {
    public $with = app()->isProduction() ? ['relation_x','relation_y','etc'] : [];
    ...
```

However, this causes a failure of the model to instantiate because Laravel treats the $with array as a sort of static property.

I know you can conditionally turn on/off requirements for eager loading in the AppServiceProvider using:

```
Model::preventLazyLoading(! app()->isProduction())
```

However, this doesn't accomplish exactly what I want, and I'm not interested in a global solution. I also know that you can override eager loads on inidividual requests like this:

```
Model::setEagerLoads([])->get()
```

Unfortunately, neither of these solutions works for me because I don't want global declarations for eager loading and I don't want to have to conditionally scope every one of my Post queries. I wish I could just wrap some of the construct arrays in an environment check, if possible, but don't know how to achieve that. I also don't want to have to build custom model extensions to use locally because that's just too much code bloat. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know the exact logic, as it's PHP-level code, but using a `?`, or other things like `private $whatever = collect(['1', '2']);` (as an example) are not valid for declaring class properties. Typically, you can get around this with a `__construct()` method, but I'm not sure if this specific case would work with that (i.e. `public function __construct() { $this->with = app()->isProduction() ? [...] : [...]; }`. Some properties can be overridden at runtime, like `$model->timestamps = false` will disable `created_at`/`updated_at` for the current request, etc., but not sure about `with`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try instead of `Model::preventLazyLoading(! app()->isProduction())`
you can specify which model you want `Post::preventLazyLoading(! app()->isProduction())` ?

Since `Post::class` is also and instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class`.

Comment: Yes I tried that and while it “works”, it doesn’t accomplish what I need. Really all that this does is tell Laravel to throw an error if it sees that you’re lazy loading on a specific model. I don’t need the errors thrown, I need to actually override the behavior itself.